# Focus on Validation Summary List

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a long page to be filled in by the user so if the user gets an error, sometimes they're wondering what happened, since the focus will be on the textbox or label where error occurred not knowing what to do next. I wish to focus instead on the validation summary list instead of where the error is so they can read first what's wrong. Would you please help on me on how to achieve this like an example. I tried to put the focus the validation summary  but I guess it's not working. Thank you!

Comment: You can show a mouse twxtbox or add a help page where you can jump, last you can us leave focus to validate or the validate from each element